# Advice on partial answers

Tags: discussion

I need advice on handling one of [my questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19969/4559).

I originally asked for help to identify the subject of the dependent clause in this sentence:

> A. Germany adopted a much weaker currency than would otherwise have been the case

I wrongly arrived to the conclusion that *"the case"* couldn't be subject and offered the following sentence as a counter-example:

> B. Germany adopted a much weaker currency than would otherwise have been possible

Now, it turns out I don't have one question but two!

I found myself an answer for sentence A. At the same time, *user2619* found an answer for sentence B.

I would like to award the answer to *user2619* but I'm thinking whether:

- I should ask *user2619* to complete their answer and remove mine,
- or just be pragmatic and leave both answers as they are.

What do you think is best?

Comment: I'd like to read both answers. :-)